# Lossless and lossy image compression algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm learning about image processing. I want to know about lossless and lossy image compression algorithm. Anybody can give me any suggestions ? Thanks so much!

Comment: What questions do you have? Wikipedia has a [lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless) of [good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy) information.

Comment: Possibly more suited for math.stackexchange.  You'll want to look at the theory (Huffman encoding, matrix decomposition) and the implementations (png, jpg), which typically use much more sophisticated but conceptually similar techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lossy compression algorithms don't provide a perfect bit-for-bit copy when decoded, but they usually achieve a smaller file size. A typical lossy format is JPEG, and a typical lossless format is PNG 24 bit or TIFF. A more modern lossy format is JPEG-2000, but it is not very common.

Lossy formats work by transforming the image into another domain (DCT for JPEG, Wavelet for JPEG 2000) where bands of information can be limited with minimal damage to the visibility of the image.

Lossless formats may perform compression or not. If they compress they use a method such as [LZW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lzw) which can provide the exact bit stream as output as they were given as input, similar to zip compression.

Comment: Great! Can you share me any references ?

Comment: @Alen, I'd start with Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpeg for example.