# Compressing image in android is loosing the quality when image is taken from phone camera

Tags: android, image-compression

I am using this method for compressing the image https://gist.github.com/ManzzBaria/c3af85b708fee49d55f7

but my images are loosing quality after compression. it is worse when an image is take from phone and compressed.

Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: This code seems chiefly to be *scaling* the image to a smaller size. This is not the same as [compressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_compression) the image (though it is also doing that, in line 121). Can you clarify exactly what you want to do?

Comment: @kwinkunks I am trying to scale the image and also reduce the size of image before uploading to server

Comment: Reduce the size of the *image* (pixels), or the size of the *file* (bytes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing the size of the *image* takes pixels away, effectively reducing the resolution of the image. Of course, the file also gets smaller. If you save as a high-fidelity JPEG (say 95%), this may be all the file size reduction you need.

Reducing the size of the *file* with a [lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) method (eg [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)) will achieve a reduction in file size with no loss of quality — hence the name. The reduction depends on the image: a picture with many identical pixels, eg a screenshot of this page, will compress substantially.

Using a [lossy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) method (eg normal JPEG compression) will result in an even smaller file, but you will pay for this reduction with a loss of quality. Most methods of saving JPEGs allow you to choose a fidelity, often 80% by default, which controls the quality of the resulting image; this is the line that does it in the code you posted:

```
scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
```

Again, the reduction you achieve is inversely proportional to the complexity of the image, as well as to this fidelity parameter.

Here's a blog post I wrote on choosing image formats: [How to choose an image format](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2012/8/7/how-to-choose-an-image-format.html). [This one](http://www.agilegeoscience.com/blog/2014/1/23/save-the-samples.html) might also be worth reading.

There are more good links on lossy vs lossless compression in @Gavriel's answer.

Comment: Sorry kwinkunks, actually the problem is when i click an image and get the path of the image from my app the image quality has been reduced. Dont know why. To get the path of the image by setting the image to bitmap. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Where are the reduced quality images coming from? If they were saved by the code you posted, then there's your answer. Or are they from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about lossy and lossless image compression:

- [Lossless and lossy image compression algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962359/lossless-and-lossy-image-compression-algorithm)
- [PHP Compress Image with Lossy/Lossless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032976/php-compress-image-with-lossy-lossless)
- [jpeg compression - lossy or lossless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153389/jpeg-compression-lossy-or-lossless)